# Advice on form for dynamic data entry into an html page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms

I have a project where I have to output some safety information on monitors. I have it working perfectly but the dates in it are dynamic and I need a form to make it easy for anyone to change the information. Here's the code for one of the pages.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>First Aid Days</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*circle image */
        #imgFirstaid { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 110px; z-index: 0; } 

        /* large xx of days in the center of the circle */
        #strFirstaid{ width: 579px; height: 579px; text-align: center; margin-top: 125px; position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 115px; z-index: 0; font-family: calibri; font-weight: bold; font-size: 250px; color: #403152;  } 

        /* small date at the bottom of the circle */
        #txtFirstaid{ width: 579px; height: 579px; text-align: center; margin-top: 365px; position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 115px; z-index: 0; font-family: calibri; font-size: 28px; color: #403152;  }
    </style>
    <script>

    function GetFirstaid(){

    var then = new Date(2013, 2, 27), // month is zero based, i.e. jan = 0 (yyyy, m, dd)
        now = new Date;               // no arguments -> current date
    // 24 hours, 60 minutes, 60 seconds, 1000 milliseconds
    out=Math.abs((now - then) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // round the amount of days
    rou=Math.round(out)
    document.getElementById('strFirstaid').innerHTML=rou;
    }
    window.onload=function(){GetFirstaid();}//call when everything has loaded

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="imgFirstaid"><img src="../images/lg-f.png" /></div>
    <div id="strFirstaid"></div>
    <div id="txtFirstaid">_____________________ <br />03/27/2013</div> <!-- enter the date as normal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, the output works great now but I'm trying to figure out if I can tie in a form with this html or if I'll need to start over and use some ASP or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this. One (like you mentioned) is via a form; and the other is to ask for the date using the "prompt" javascript method.

**Here's approach one (with form) ::**
Throw in the form just before the body tag like so -

```
    <form action="">
      Enter date: <input type="text" name="then" value="" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

As you can see, this form will basically calls the same page itself and appends the form parameters. So if you type a date, say "4/27/2013", and press ENTER, you'll end up getting redirected to the same page, but this time it will have ?then=4%2F27%2F2013 in the end.

Now, all you need is parse this in your GetFirstaid method. So instead of using the hard coded date in the "then" variable, you'd do this -

```
        var thenStr = window.location.search.substr(6);
        var thenDtArr = thenStr.split("%2F");
        var then = new Date(thenDtArr[2], thenDtArr[0], thenDtArr[1]);
```

You should (obviously) do all the error handling and number formatting checks; I have avoided that to keep this discussion simple.

**Here's the approach two (with prompt method) ::**
In this method, you don't need a form. You simply hit the page, and the first thing it does is prompts you to enter the date. So all you need is this in your GetFirstaid method (in the beginning of the method) -

```
        thenStr = prompt("Please Enter a date:");
        var then = null;
        if (thenStr != null && thenStr != "") {
          var thenDtArr = thenStr.split("/");
          then = new Date(thenDtArr[2], thenDtArr[0], thenDtArr[1]);
        }
```

One extra thing, I'd do is update the "txtFirstaid" field so as to reflect the date the user entered. So, just under where you are rendering strFirstaid, add one more line to update txtFirstaid, like so -

```
    document.getElementById('strFirstaid').innerHTML=rou;
    document.getElementById('txtFirstaid').innerHTML = "_____________________ <br />"+thenDtArr[0]+"/"+thenDtArr[1]+"/"+thenDtArr[2];
```

Hope this helps.